# How to compile example program using libmosquitto

Tags: libmosquitto

I am getting the following errors when I try to compile one of the example:

```
main.cpp:8:undefined reference to `mosqpp::lib_init()'
main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::loop(int, int)'
main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::reconnect()'
temperature_conversion.o: In function `mqtt_tempconv':
temperature_conversion.cpp:7: undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::mosquittopp(char const*, bool)'
temperature_conversion.cpp:13: undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::connect(char const*, int, int)'
temperature_conversion.cpp:7: undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::~mosquittopp()'
temperature_conversion.o: In function `mqtt_tempconv::on_connect(int)':
temperature_conversion.cpp:21: undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::subscribe(int*, char const*, int)'
temperature_conversion.o: In function `mqtt_tempconv::on_message(mosquitto_message const*)':
temperature_conversion.cpp:37: undefined reference to `mosqpp::mosquittopp::publish(int*, char const*, int, void const*, int, bool)'
```

Please help

Comment: Please show your compile and link commands. Also see [How to compile using libmosquitto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19707329/608639)

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't give much detail - you should describe *how* you've gone about it as well as what the problem is.

Having said that, it looks like you haven't linked against the library.

If you are compiling like this:

```
g++ main.o temperature_conversion.o -o temperature_conversion
```

Then you need to link against the library:

```
g++ main.o temperature_conversion.o -o temperature_conversion -lmosquittopp
```

I'm assuming it is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

`locate libmosquittopp.so` can help you understanding the directory to give to g++ as -L parameter.

```
g++ main.o temperature_conversion.o -o temperature_conversion -lmosquittopp \
    -L$(locate libmosquitto.so | tail -n 1 | xargs -n1 dirname)
```